# Speaker audio is not working, but headset audio is working

Tags: sound, alsa

My laptop is a Thinkpad T410 and after using Ubuntu Studio, I've tried to reinstall Alsamixer and PulseAudio to no avail. I'm very confused as to why this problem suddenly appeared (i haven't updated anything in a while).

Comment: Your Question states that it should be some issue with internal speaker.. Is Speaker working for system sound or you are facing this for all audio?

Comment: I should've mentioned that the system sound works when I plug in my headset, but otherwise the speaker does not work at all.